Spring cloud AWS is not able to load keys from custom directory
I am trying to access AWS access key and token Spring Boot and Spring Cloud AWS from a custom place '/usr/etc/cicd/'. I am using spring boot 3.3. with AWS cloud 2023.0.3 dependency. I have added the spring-boot-aws-starter version 3.2.0-M1. it always pick the credentials from my home directory, for ex: c:/users/<user_name>/.aws/credentials. If I put the files at home location, everything works fine.
so far, I tried:

Give a try with different formats of application.yml
created the bean with awsCredentialsProvider but nothing worked

My application.yml file is below
server:
  port: 9002

spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  application:
    name: mca-config-server
  profiles:
    active: awsparamstore
  cloud:
    aws:
      region:
        static:  us-west-2
      credentials:
          profile:
            name: default
            path:  /usr/etc/cicd/.aws/credentials
      server:
        awsparamstore:
          prefix: /config
          profile-separator: _
          recursive: true
          decrypt-values: true
          max-results: 5

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:9072/eureka
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true

mca:
  config:
    issuer: MCA
    subject: MCA
    privateKey: /usr/etc/configServer/configPrivateKey

POM dependencies are below:
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring.boot.version>3.3.2</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.cloud.version>2023.0.3</spring.cloud.version>
        <awssdk.bom.version>2.23.10</awssdk.bom.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <bouncycastle.version>1.78</bouncycastle.version>
        <log4j.version>2.23.1</log4j.version>
        <jjwt.api.version>0.11.5</jjwt.api.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0-M1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>ssm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.api.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jjwt.api.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.40</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${awssdk.bom.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- overriding below dependencies to fix WS policy violation-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
                <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0-b42</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache</artifactId>
                <version>6.10.0.202406032230-r</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

My config file is below
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

       
    @Autowired
    private ConfigServerAuthenticateProvider configServerAuthenticateProvider;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;


    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new ConfigServerAuthenticateFilter(authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager()), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }


   

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        return http
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .logout(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement-> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(configServerAuthenticateProvider)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize-> authorize.requestMatchers("/**").authenticated())
                .build();
    }

    @Order(1)
    @Bean(name= "awsCredentialsProvider")
    public AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider() {
        return () -> {
            try {
                ProfileFile profileFile = ProfileFile.builder()
                        .content(Paths.get("/usr/etc/mca/cicd/.aws/profile")) // Change this path as necessary
                        .type(ProfileFile.Type.CREDENTIALS)
                        .build();
                // Load credentials from the specified file path and profile
                return ProfileCredentialsProvider.builder()
                        .profileFile(profileFile)
                        .profileName(PROFILE_NAME)
                        .build()
                        .resolveCredentials();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Handle exception if credentials are not available
                throw SdkClientException.create("Unable to load credentials from the specified file", e);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SsmClient ssmClient(AwsCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
        return SsmClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_WEST_2) // Ensure the region is set
                .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .credentialsProvider(DefaultCredentialsProvider.create()) // Use DefaultCredentialsProvider
                .build();
    }

}

